# Не возвращаются данные PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Написал скрипт который должен якобы выводить с другого файла echo например 123, запрос есть ,а ответ не дает .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <script>

//создаем объект  ajax
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //создаем объект  ajax    

function get_inform() {

    // переменные для данной функции
    var inform  ;   // полученная информация в формате json
    var nmbr;       // кол-во  объектов json

        // обрабатываем  ответ от сервера на свой запрос    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    console.log('i have ... ');    
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        inform = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        nmbr = inform.length;
        console.log('answer = ' + xmlhttp.responseText);        
        console.log('you have nmbr = ' + nmbr);         


    }else{
        console.log('not corr... ');
        console.log('answer = ' + xmlhttp.responseText); 
    }
    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","jsonp.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 

    setTimeout(get_inform, 1000); 
}

get_inform();   // запрос информации с сервера    

</script>
```

**jsonp.php**

```
    <?php

$answer = '[{"obj":"01","type":"01"}]' ;

echo  $answer ;

//echo "12345678";

?>
```

Comment: "а ответ не дает" - вообще не дает?

Comment: Да . Должно было по идее возвращать [{"obj":"01","type":"01"}]

Comment: А что дает? Что-нибудь в консоль выводится?

Comment: Сейчас скрин отправлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/CHARTS-SCADA/index.html`

Поставьте какой-нибудь локальный сервер. Кто-то же должен выполнить код PHP. А у Вас просто возвращается содержимое файла `jsonp.php`.

Comment: а ксамп не подходит разве ?)

Comment: @Karter Не понял. Вам нужно, чтобы браузер обращался к серверу/программе, которая по запросу способна выполнить скрипт PHP. Вы сейчас обращаетесь к файловой системе, которая способна только вернуть содержимое файла.